# AWS multiple schedule tasks with Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, message-queue

I have the following application scenario.

I need to call an API in my server based on multiple user actions and rules. In my web app an user might click a button and I need to schedule an event after `X` amount of time where `X` value depends on user configuration. The event has to trigger a callback to an API that will process some data.

In order to achieve this I was thinking in multiple ways using `AWS` services. So, once the user clicks my web app button server will:

**SQS Approach**

1. Create a `SQS` queue, then have a `Lambda` function run every 2 minutes and check queue by queue to see if a metadata timestamp value is on time to execute the API call. Once API call is done, delete the queue.

The problem here is that I could have 10,000 concurrent users clicking its own button, that means 10,000 queues and each queue will have its own metadata timestamp value that is my scheduled time when `Lambda` needs to call API. And from reading there is no way to query `SQS` based on metadata values: Ex. Get all queues where timestamp is equal or less than actual time.

Also I was looking into Queue delay functionality to only make visible the queues that needs to be executed but the downside is that delay max value is 15 minutes and I can have scheduled times greater than 6 hours.

**DynamoDB Approach**

2. Instead of using `SQS`, server will create a `DynamoDB` record. Then `Lambda` is executed every 2 minutes and will pull all table records and loop each one validating if Timestamp member is equal or less than actual time, if so then call API and delete DB record.

This scenario might look better because I guess the performance of getting records from `DynamoDB` is faster (Is a guess) but again it lacks of a powerful query because I can only query primary key. I was reading I can do scan but don’t know if it’s possible to scan based on date & time values.

**Cloudwatch Approach**

3. Instead of using `SQS` or `DynamoDB`, on every user button click, server will have to create a `Cloudwatch` rule that will have the scheduled time when I need `Lambda` function to be triggered. Once `Lambda` is executed and API called, `Lambda` will need to delete the `Cloudwatch` rule so it won’t execute it again.

This scenario will require the creation of thousands of `Cloudwatch` rules and don’t know if this is possible, but I like this Approach because I don’t have to pull data, loop each item, validate timestamp and trigger `Lambda` because `Cloudwatch` does it automatically.

> Any advice or clue on which one is the correct approach or maybe I’m missing others. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use any of your outlined approaches. Instead, I would develop a solution that leverages Amazon Step Functions.

When the user clicks the button, a step function is instantiated where one of first steps is a parameterized wait state. That will give you the user configured waiting time, and can be as long or as short as you want. After the wait state, you can do the rest of your steps in your workflow.

All of the approaches you outlined seem clunky, brittle, and expensive compared to using step functions. Having a serverless answer to this allows you to scale seamlessly and operate efficiently.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-wait-state.html

Comment: Hi Chris, is it possible to delete a instantiated step function? Or is there a way I can update the wait time? Thanks

Comment: Other question, having a wait for example of 6 hours won’t generate a cost of that state machine?

Comment: You don’t pay while it’s in the wait state. You should be able to cancel; but not update the wait time.

Comment: So it’s possible when instantiated the step function to pass parameters? For example I will need to pass like 5 parameters so when the lambda function is called it can receive them.

Comment: I already implement using Step Functions and is awesomeeeee. Just awesome. Thanks a lot

Comment: That’s great to hear!

Comment: Hi, I posted other question about Step Functions here just in case you know about that. Appreciate it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48631220/aws-step-functions-with-multiple-executions

Answer (score 2):

#### Dynamo approach

I think this is the best way for you to go. You can actually have what's called a [composite primary key](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.CoreComponents.html): "*this type of key is composed of two attributes. The first attribute is the partition key, and the second attribute is the sort key*".

Your sort key could be the timestamp of when your job should be executed for example. This way you could query the Primary Key (aka Hash attribute) **AND** Sort key (aka Partition key) at the same time, in order to retrieve only jobs that are due to be executed at some point in time, without the need of a scan.

OBS.: *`now()` would be a function that returns the current timestamp.*

1. Upon user button click, generate a timestamp of when the request should run (e.g. 5 hours from now = `now() + 60 * 60 * 5`) and save this timestamp as the Sort key in Dynamo.
2. In your Lambda function (auto-triggered every 2 min.), you'll query Dynamo to retrieve requests with `sort_key < now()`, which will retrieve all requests that are due to be executed at that particular point in time.
3. After processing, you'd delete requestes from Dynamo or flag them as executed.

Beware that Dynamo limits the number of items to be returned in a single query and the size (in MB) of the query results as a whole. Also, Lambda has an execution time limit of 5 minutes. Depending on how long your processing takes and how many requests are due to be processed at some point, you'll need to split it in chunks, otherwise Lambda could timeout, for example.

Various approaches could be used here:

- The same Lambda function calls itself at the end of each job to continue processing pending requests (if there're any). This is easier to implement, but the downside is when you have too many chunks: the latter ones would be delayed (they'll be waiting for the first ones to be executed). The delay could be problematic, since your users expected to have the job processed earlier.
- You could have a Composer function that retrieves everything from Dynamo (could run multiple queries, if there're too many pending jobs) and trigger another Lambda function multiple times in parallel (in asynchronous mode). This second Lambda would be responsible for actually doing all the heavy lifting. The advantage of this approach is that every chunk of job requests will be executed almost simultaneously, which prevents undesirable delays.

> Below is simple example of what a composer function would do in your case. I used Python syntax but should be simple for you to understand.

```py
# In the Composer Lambda function:

# First, you'd get all scheduled tasks from DynamoDB
tasks = get_pending_tasks()

# Then you'd break it in multiple chunks before calling the Worker function
max_tasks_per_worker = 100
if len(tasks) <= max_tasks_per_worker:
    call_worker(tasks=tasks)

elif len(tasks) > max_tasks_per_worker:
    chunks = split_list(tasks, size=max_tasks_per_worker)
    for chunk in chunks:
        call_worker(tasks=chunk)

# split_list() just splits a list in chunks of n size
# Example: let's say you have a list of 240 items and want chunks of 100
# This function will return 3 lists with 100, 100, and 40 items each

# call_worker() just triggers another Lambda function that will actually
# execute the tasks that were scheduled

# You could use multiple threads to parallelize calls to the call_worker()
```

#### SQS approach

As you already expressed, SQS is not the tool to handle this kind of use case.

#### Cloudwatch (CW) approach

The problem here is that CW has a limit of [100 rules per region per account](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/cloudwatch_limits_cwe.html). You can request an increase, but I don't thing they'll allow you to have up to tens or hundreds of thousands of rules. It wasn't meant for this kind of use case.

If you don't need granularity in your scheduling, you could still use CW by setting standard rules that could be shared by different users. For example:

1. Setup 24 rules to run every hour, so that you cover an entire day span. You identify each rule with the hour of the day: "rule1:00AM", "rule2:00AM", etc.
2. Let's say it's 7 AM UTC and a user wants to schedule something for 3 hours from now. You'll save this request in Dynamo with a primary key like `rule10:00AM-reqXYZ123`.
3. At 10:00 AM, the appropriate CW rule will trigger Lambda, which will retrieve from Dynamo all requests with a Primary key that begins with "rule10:00AM" (see BEGIN_WITH in [Conditional Queries](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Condition.html)). Then you can process the request normally on Lambda.
4. After processing, you'd delete requestes from Dynamo or flag them as executed.

Also observe the same limits I mentioned above for Dynamo and Lambda. In case you need more granularity, you could have 48 CW rules running every 30 minutes, or 96 CW rules running every 15 minutes. But anyway, I prefer the Dynamo approach above. It will take you more time to implement, but it's way more flexible and reusable.

Comment: Very interesting. Appreciate your reply. Do you know where can I get more info about doing the Composer function for chunk processing? Because for sure I will need this :)

Comment: Appreciate so much your feedback, I ended using Steps Functions and is working amazing. Anyway all your comments are very valuable to me.

Comment: Let's say you have a "Worker" Lambda function that does the processing jobs and this Worker can process 100 requests in up to 5 minutes (Lambda limit). The Composer would just retrieve everything from Dynamo and check how many requests are there. If there's more than 100, it'll split in chunks of 100 each and call the Worker several times, passing one chunk per call. This way, the Worker would be triggered multiple times in parallel and process as many requests as you need, without worrying with Lambda timing out.

Comment: Very insteresting, do you have any link where I can read more about Composer and if you have any link for a tutorial please I would really appreciate it.

Comment: I added a simple example in my answer above. It's just an idea that I use in my projects when I need more flexibility in distributing work among Lambda functions. I don't know about a tutorial exactly about this, although it's not super innovative and there must be something similar already published somewhere on the internet (probably not named "composer").

Answer (score 1):

Although you have found your answer by using Step Function, I still would like to share my opinion on this since your use case is quite similar to mine and I end up using DynamoDB.

However, rather than using Lambda to query and validate the timestamp, my approach is using the DynamoDB's Time-To-Live (the timestamp column is set as the TTL) in which the record in the table will be deleted when it expires and the deleted record will appear in DynamoDB stream. Once it appear in the stream, a Lambda can be triggered for further processing.  You may find the docs about [TTL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/TTL.html) and [Stream](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.Lambda.html) here.

So in general, my apps will register a process event by adding a record in DynamoDB with a timestamp when the event should occur (the timestamp is the TTL). Then, once the the timestamp reached, DynamoDB deletes the record and put it into the stream that will trigger a Lambda to start the event.

The decision to use this approach was because another use case where my app requires to be able to **view/edit/delete** the "scheduled event". So as long as the records still in the table, I still can manipulate them.

Comment: Mmm this is exactly the case I have. Right now with Step Functions I stop the execution and because there is no way to edit an execution I create a new execution with new parameters. Do you have any link I can read about TTL and streams?

Comment: Actually what do you need to setup in order to pass to Stream once the record is deleted?

Comment: This link https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.Lambda.Tutorial.html will help you to go through from enabling the stream and link it with Lambda. Take note that all activities (insert/update/delete) on record will be available in the stream. So once the TTL kicks in, the record will automatically available in the stream.

Comment: So that means that when inserting a record into DynamoDB with ttl it will go to stream and then it will trigger the lambda funcction? How can I make that only when the ttl expires and the record is deleted, then the lambda function is called? Or is there a way to know from Lambda function if the record as an insert, update or delete to do the logic there?

Comment: There is eventName in the payload of every record in the stream. It could be INSERT/MODIFY/REMOVE as the value of the eventName. So you have to do some logic in the Lambda to ensure only entertains those with REMOVE event. Checkout here as the sample of the record https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/eventsources.html#eventsources-ddb-update

Comment: Amazing!! Love it. Appreciate it so much

Comment: According to the docs, items MAY not get deleted right away with TTL. "DynamoDB typically deletes expired items within 48 hours of expiration. The exact duration within which an item truly gets deleted after expiration is specific to the nature of the workload and the size of the table. Items that have expired and have not been deleted still appear in reads, queries, and scans. These items can still be updated, and successful updates to change or remove the expiration attribute are honored."